# From python 3 to Python 2 (print())

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I think the piece of code below is written in python 3 and my python 2 cannot run it. There is some problem with 'end'. How could I fix it? I don't know what is the logic behind end an i am very new to python

Any help much appreciated!

```
def myPrint(itp):
    for i in range(10):
        print("**",end=="")
        for j in range(10):
            print(itp[i][j],"**",end=="")
        print()
```

Comment: "some problem"... Have you tried reading about Python 2's `print` statement and Python 3's `print` function? It looks like you got an error message and immediately asked a question without doing any research (which you are expected to do before asking a new question).

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your code, you need to replace both `end==""` with `end=""`. You are not supposed to compare the parameter `end` with an empty string, but you want to end the printing with an empty string, hence, do an assignment to the parameter `end`.

In `Python 3.x`, the `end=''` part will place a whatever parameter `end` is assigned with (here, an empty string) after the displayed string instead of a newline.

If you want to have the print functionality of `python3` in `python2`, simply do an import :

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: I know, but i am getting an error SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you show the error ?

Comment: ok now it is getting better, but it wont allow me to print simple expressions like: print var

Comment: This is because you need to have the parentheses around the expression.

Comment: Can you post the *entire* code that generates the SyntaxError? [Here is an online demo that works fine for me](http://ideone.com/5cuGrO)

Comment: I suppose your issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted :) @StatLearner

Answer (score 0):

(I am assuming the double == after `end` is a typo. end as a [kwarg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1769403/35070) determines the end of line; the code likely originally was `print("**",end="")` with one `=` character)

To get print function semantics, you can set the [`__future__` flag `print_function`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html), by starting your file with

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Be aware that the changes required to run a full Python 3 program under Python 2 are far more extensive than simply enabling some future flags (while you're add it, consider enabling `unicode_literals`). By far the easiest way to run a Python 3 program is to install a Python 3 interpreter.